# Rails_admin permission on edit view of specific model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` gem with `rails` 4. Currently I am using this method

```
# Authorize just admin for '/admin'
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless warden.user.admin == true
  end
```

under `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` to permit only the admin user to access the dashboard. PROBLEM: if the current user is admin and he/she is trying to change her permission to regular user (unticking) `admin` box then they get an error saying that `no method for nil:admin` - this is happening because `/admin` is no longer available for this regular user. QUESTION: How can I disallow the current user edit his own `admin` property ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just overid `app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_boolean.html.erb` with

```
<!-- Do not authorize current user to change his own admin property -->
<% if (field.name.to_s == "admin") && (request.original_fullpath.split("/")[-2].to_s == _current_user.id.to_s) %>
<p style = "color:red; margin-top: 10px; font-weight: bold;"> unavailable for this account </p>
<% else %>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label style="display: block;">
        <%= form.send field.view_helper, field.method_name, field.html_attributes.reverse_merge({ value: field.form_value, checked: field.form_value.in?([true, '1']), required: field.required}) %>
    </label>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and then, in my `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
edit do
      field :email  do
        required true
      end
      field :admin
      field :password  do
        required true
      end
      field :password_confirmation do
        required true
      end
      field :id, :hidden do
        default_value do
          bindings[:view]._current_user.id
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to see if the user that they are editing matches the current_user when they press the edit button on the list of users (the information of the current user can be grabbed as `_current_user` from the rails_admin) and check if the two unique user id/token matches. If they do match then you can disable the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I solved it somehow else, check my asnwer!